# How to get row index in p:orderList?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple implementation of p:orderList in which I display array list of task objects, namely task name and commandButton which displays more details about task:

```
<p:orderList value="#{taskBean.tasks}" var="t" controlsLocation="none"
           itemValue="#{t}" id="tasks"/>
        <p:column>   
             <h:outputLabel value="#{t.name}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column><h:form>
           <p:commandButton title="Details" oncomplete="#{taskBean.details(t.id)}" 
              icon="ui-icon-document-b"/>
        </h:form></p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

The button calls bean method which finds task in array list whit task id and displays it. 
Now for some reason, in all rows in orderList I end up whit last (t.id) as attribute for all buttons, so they all display the last task.

Any idea what should I do?

And my second question is how to add button which saves current order of the array list of tasks?

Comment: Something is wrong here. `oncomplete` is a Javascript callback. `#{taskBean.details(t.id)}` returns Javascript code?! OR you want to call `taskBean.details` method on button click? You should use `action` attribute then.

Comment: no, it all works well, details(t.id) returns string wich displays dialog with details. It's just this t.id that ends whit same value for all rows...

Comment: you should place some client side code like `oncomplete="#{alert('t.id')}"` instead of referring to a bean method like you did...

Comment: I see, but I still need to dig up the right task object from array list, that's why I use bean...

Comment: you mean something like `<p:commandButton title="Details"  action="#{taskBean.details(t.id)}" icon="ui-icon-document-b"/>` *(using action attribute?)*

Comment: yep, but it ends up whit same t.id for all methods ... oh, and it has to be oncomplete, not action...

Comment: what is the scope of your `taskBean` ?

Comment: know that : you can't run bean method using the `oncomplete` , it for running client side code only...

Comment: See the example of details popup in [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf). Just do it the same way.